# Sphinx doc error "no module named 'qgis'" with QGIS python plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, documentation

I try to generate my PyQGIS plugin documentation with Sphinx.

I made a python virtualenv based on QGIS environment and initiated my Sphinx doc with the package already installed in it.

But when I generate the html doc, I get this error :

`WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'mymodule' from module 'mainmodule'; the following exception was raised: No module named 'qgis'`

How can I tell sphinx where to find QGIS ?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found is to remove my sphinx from standard python installation and install it inside my venv.

But then, I get another error :

```
No module named 'processing'
```

I tried to add the path to processing plugin in my QGIS installation folder in the conf.py :

```
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(QgsApplication.pkgDataPath(), "python/plugins")))
```

which doesn't work (I verified the value of `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(QgsApplication.pkgDataPath(), "python/plugins"))` which points well to the processing directory.

EDIT : `os.path.join(QgsApplication.pkgDataPath(), "python/plugins")` returns only complete QGIS path within QGIS python console, otherwise QgsApplication needs to be initialized with QGIS path. The simplest way to get QGIS path is to hardcode it directly in the conf.py